# How to call a specific element in an array with another array?

Tags: python, arrays

Im new to python and I stumbled on this problem, I would like to call a specific element in an array, but the array name is controlled by another array:

```
array1 = ["foo","bar","fubar"]
array2 = ["array1","array3","array4"]
number = 2

inter = array2[0]
test = inter[number]
#what im trying to achieve: test = array1[2]
#expecting: fubar
#what im getting: r
print(test)
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: These are python `list` objects. But anyway, you simply have strings in your second list. The fact that those strings happen to be the same as the variable names is nothing those lists know about. You *can* dynamically execute strings as code, but there is no need for that, it is a fundamentally bad design choice. Use another data structure, like a dict, if you want to map strings to other objects.

Comment: Just wondering, don't you mean to use a  `dict` to map strings to objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use strings but references to the arrays.

```
array1 = ["foo","bar","fubar"]
array2 = [array1, array3, array4] # use references instead of strings here
number = 2

inter = array2[0]
test = inter[number]
print(test)
```

Comment: You answered first with better wording, I'll delete mine. Fast response!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the array that you need not the name of the array.

To make things work you have to do like shown below. Assuming array3 and array4 are defined earlier

```
array1 = ["foo","bar","fubar"]
array3 = []
array4 = []
array2 = [array1,array3,array4]
number = 2

inter = array2[0]
test = inter[number]
print(test)
```